# Informal way of asking someone to make a PC screen window bigger

Tags: phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

Imagine your 5–7 year son is watching a movie for children on a small window on the computer, and you want him to make it full screen. How would you ask him for that, using everyday language and in the least words? Is there a phrasal verb for this scenario with an "up", "out" or similar?

Comment: The first word came to mind was *enlarge*. Then I thought *zoom out* or *zoom up* might be better. Then again, I realized that there is a word for this purpose *"maximize the window"*. I'm not sure if it suits the children well enough, but I believe they will understand the word.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think they are everyday words. I don't think "zoom in" is the same as make the window bigger or full screen. Even if the child understands them, to me, they are not the right register.

Comment: I believe I have seen *zoom up* or *max it up* used a few time, but I'm not sure if they're good words for children. They sound a bit slang for me. I put them here as choices, for they might be helpful.

Comment: Good suggestions @DamkerngT. I'll check them out. Meanwhile I found this (but I'm hesitant): "How big can I print my photos is a very common question. Even professional photographers occasionally struggle with the question of just how big can they **blow up** their images. The bottom line on how big you can print your photos depends on a couple of factors. First, how much information (photo data) is there? Second, What is the intended viewing distance from the print? Third, what material will the photo be printed on?"

Comment: Max it up: "Actually, the one thing that has annoyed me so far about Quicktime X is that there seems to be no way to zoom in on the trim bar. So all you can do to add precision to your trimming is to resize the window, but obviously your screen is only so large and longer movies compress the trim timeline. With 20-ish minute standard definition footage, I find I'm limited to 2 second precision trims at the default window size, 1 second if I **max it up** to full screen."

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean. I'm sure that you can say *blow up* with photos, but not sure in the context of windows on a screen. (I think it's okay.) The phrase *max it up* sounds like something said by a tech guy, especially one who works with computer graphics and multimedia.

Comment: Macmillan's gives this for **zoom up**: "3 [intransitive] to suddenly increase in price, quantity, or **size**
"*The price started at forty pounds, then zoomed up to a hundred.*"". I can use one of yours now, but I am just curios what native speakers would say! You could make an answer out of all the comments @DamkerngT.

Comment: If you want informal, *make the window bigger* seems fine to me.

Comment: The standard term for enlarging a window to full screen is *maximize*. There's no reason not to use that with a 5-year-old; if he doesn't understand it, you can explain it, and Whaddayaknow! He's learned a new word! Some *concepts* - what you talk *about* - may be difficult for children, but words are just interesting noises, and big words are mostly noisier and more fun than little words.

Comment: [Embiggen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embiggen) of course, a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: Hasn't the OP answered his own question? What's wrong with the simple "make it full screen"? That's what I would say, and not only to a child.

Answer (score 1):

[Native:Australian]

As mentioned in comments above, "maximise" is the correct terminology here.  I have small children (2, 3, 6) and they are all OK with that.

If you want to make that sound a bit more fun can I suggest making up a few words that sound like they should exist but are a bit too silly:

- Embigginate
- Zoomify
- Go full
- Max it to 11 (that is a movie reference to [This is Spinal Tap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_Spinal_Tap))

Comment: I like the sound of *embigginate*. :)

Comment: Wow, I'd rather stick with make it bigger!

Comment: Or "embiggen", from "The Simpsons."